# Microsoft Bot Framework and attachments

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot that works perfect but when I try to include attachments gives me Internal Server Error, what am I doing wrong? I use the Microsoft Bot Framework example.

```
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.ContentType = "image/png";
attachment.ContentUrl = "http://www.southsystem.net/ss3blue3d.jpg";
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("test");
reply.Attachments.Add(attachment); // need to comment to work
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

if I comment the `Attachments.Add` all works great and gives me no error. I'm dealing with this for days and tried everything. Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `Attachments` list before adding the attachment.

```
reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Comment: Was this useful?

Comment: Many many thanks, thats what I had missing, I tried before but needed System.Collections.Generic. Nothing like having this done first thing in the morning. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

According to previous answer :

If you want to reply without list of attachments you have to create something like this :

```
var msg = context.MakeMessage();
msg.Text = "some text for your attachment";
msg.Attachments.Add(att);
await context.PostAsync(msg);
```

You must have some text into reply message. Otherwise, it gives no error but not showing the message.
I test it this way and it works.
Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Based on his code he is not doing this in the context of a dialog. So he don't have access to the dialog context.